# Not catching EmptyStackException

Tags: java

I was wondering why my code would not catch and EmptyStackException if I put 0 on stackSize.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Stack stack = new Stack();
   System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to add to the stack? >> ");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   int stackSize = scan.nextInt();

   for(int i=0; i < stackSize; i++){

       try {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            int number = scan.nextInt();
            stack.push(number);

       } catch(EmptyStackException e){
            System.out.print("Empty Stack");
       }


   }
   System.out.println(stack);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `if I put 0 on stackSize`?

Comment: Which operation do you expect to throw `EmptyStackException`?

Comment: At the start of the code. Asking a user input for how many numbers they would like to put in the stack. If a user enters zero as an answer, I assumed it would catch an empty stack exception for having an empty stack.

Comment: so if originally `0` was entered the only code that is executed is `System.out.println(stack);
`

Comment: @CharlesDalid Your first scan statement does not influence your stack in any way. It just stores an `int`, which you happen to use as boundary for your `for` loop, but that does not make it throw an exception related to stacks.

Comment: "At the start of the code" is very vague. Before the first line of the method? The user hasn't even entered the 0 at that point. I think if you'd thought about this more carefully, you'd have seen why no exception would be thrown. (In particular, you'd have looked for methods in the documentation which throw `EmptyStackException`, and spotted that your code doesn't call any of those methods.) Stepping through the debugger would have helped too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `EmptyStackException` is thrown wenn you call `Pop()` on an empty stack not when you `push` an element to an empty stack.

See this code:

```
   try {
        stack.pop();
   } catch(EmptyStackException e){
        System.out.print("Empty Stack");
   }
```

and the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop())

Comment: thanks. this clarifies everything! will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you enter stackSize as 0 then following code wont be executed because stackSize is 0

```
for(int i=0; i < stackSize; i++){

       try {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            int number = scan.nextInt();
            stack.push(number);

       } catch(EmptyStackException e){
            System.out.print("Empty Stack");
       }
```

}

And  also an EmptyStackException is thrown only when you call Pop/Delete on an empty Stack. Here nothing such as in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't invoke a method that may throw it.
`push()` doesn't throw any exception.
The javadoc confirms it.

The single methods that throw `EmptyStackException`  in `Stack` are the retrieval/removal methods : 
`pop()` and `peek()`

It means that the API is designed to ensure that the client checks that the `Stack` is not empty before trying to retrieve/remove something from it.
`EmptyStackException` is documented :

> Thrown by methods in the Stack class to indicate that the stack is
>   empty.

But it doesn't mean that it throws the exception for any invocation on a `Stack` instance where it is empty.
Besides, it would not make any sense to not be able to add element in a Stack that initially is always empty.